# Exception while user callback (MFC)

Tags: c++, windows-7, mfc, windows-10

I have a function with this header

```
 void LiveviewDlg::OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy)
```

In this function I calculate some coordinates for my controls. I use for this

```
CRect rect;
GetWindowRect(&rect);
```

to get some values from my MFC control. After the line

```
GetDlgItem(IDSTART)->MoveWindow(dialogWidth - 120, 0, 100, 50);
```

I get the exception

```
Unhandled exception at 0x5DBA4F14 (mfc120ud.dll) in Liveview.exe: 0xC000041D: Exception while user callback (translated from german to english)
```

On my Windows 7 system my program works fine. On my windows 10 system I get the exception. I don't know, why is this exception thrown.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in debug?

Comment: Yes. But only in my code. I wasnt in the MoveWindow function. The values are all correct. No null values.

Comment: I debugged through the MoveWindowFunction and found out that my window handle is NULL. `ASSERT(::IsWindow(m_hWnd) || (m_pCtrlSite != NULL));` That assert throws the exception. And `CWnd* handle = GetDlgItem(IDSTART);` returns NULL, too.

Comment: At this point, you need to figure out why the control with an ID of `IDSTART` didn't get created. What kind of control is it?

Comment: I don't understand what you say that has a NULL handle, the button or the dialog. Has the dialog already a non NULL handle?